# Add and get Images from a Task in Office 365's Planner

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use Microsoft Graph to interact with my Planner. While it does most of what I want to, I can't find a way to upload an image to a task.

Am I not looking in the right place? Or is there no way to add an image?

Thank you!

[Task reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/plannertask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task's external references are in [task details](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/plannertaskdetails) object. These are links to resources, such as an image, stored outside of Planner. You need to upload the files you want to link somewhere else (like [Group's Drive](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_get)), then add the URL of the uploaded file to the task details. You can find more information on updating task details [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/plannertaskdetails_update).

Comment: That makes sense. But what about images stored in Planner? Uploaded from Planner's web UI? Is there a way to work with those?

Comment: Planner web UI uploads them to the group's drive, then links them to the task. Planner does not store any uploads.